# Tensorflow conv2d_transpose output_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

I want to implement a Generative adversarial network (GAN) with unfixed input size, like `4-D Tensor (Batch_size, None, None, 3)`.

But when I use conv2d_transpose, there is a parameter `output_shape`, this parameter must pass the `true size` after deconvolution opeartion.

For example, if `the size of batch_img is (64, 32, 32, 128), w is weight with (3, 3, 64, 128)` , after

`deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(batch_img, w, output_shape=[64, 64, 64, 64],stride=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')`

So, I get `deconv` with `size (64, 64, 64, 64)`, it's ok if I pass the `true size of output_shape`.

But, I want to use unfixed input size `(64, None, None, 128)`, and get `deconv` with `(64, None, None, 64)`.

But, it raises an error as below.

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type'list'> to Tensor...`

So, what can I do to avoid this parameter in deconv? or is there another way to implement unfixed GAN?

Answer (score 2):

- The output shape list does not accept to have **None** in the list because the None object can not be converted to a Tensor Object
- **None** is only allowed in shapes of `tf.placeholder`
- for varying size output_shape instead of **None** try **-1** for example you want size`(64, None, None, 128)` so try `[64, -1, -1, 128]`... I am not exactly sure whether this will work... It worked for me for batch_size that is my first argument was not of fixed size so I used **-1**
- How ever there is also one high level api for transpose convolution `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose()`
- I am sure the high level api `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose()` will work for you because it takes tensors of varying inputs
- You do not even need to specify the `output-shape` you just need to specify the `output_channel` and the `kernel` to be used
- For more details : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d_transpose...  I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. Using -1, as suggested in the other answer here, doesn't work.  Instead, you have to grab the shape of the incoming tensor and construct the `output_size` argument.  Here's an excerpt from a test I wrote.  In this case it's the first dimension that's unknown, but it should work for any combination of known and unknown parameters.

```
output_shape = [8, 8, 4] # width, height, channels-out. Handle batch size later
xin = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape = (None, 4, 4, 2), name='input')
filt = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape = filter_shape, name='filter')

## Find the batch size of the input tensor and add it to the front
## of output_shape
dimxin = tf.shape(xin)
ncase = dimxin[0:1]
oshp = tf.concat([ncase,output_shape], axis=0)

z1 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(xin, filt, oshp, strides=[1,2,2,1], name='xpose_conv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to use tf.shape for unspecified shape and get_shape() for specified shape.

```
def get_deconv_lens(H, k, d):
    return tf.multiply(H, d) + k - 1

def deconv2d(x, output_shape, k_h=2, k_w=2, d_h=2, d_w=2, stddev=0.02, name='deconv2d'):
    # output_shape: the output_shape of deconv op
    shape = tf.shape(x)
    H, W = shape[1], shape[2]
    N, _, _, C = x.get_shape().as_list()
    H1 = get_deconv_lens(H, k_h, d_h)
    W1 = get_deconv_lens(W, k_w, d_w)

    with tf.variable_scope(name):
        w = tf.get_variable('weights', [k_h, k_w, C, x.get_shape()[-1]], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))
        biases = tf.get_variable('biases', shape=[C], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, w, output_shape=[N, H1, W1, C], strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1], padding='VALID')
    deconv = tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, biases)

    return deconv
```